# How to stop the mousemove event on clicking outside the window

Tags: javascript

on clicking the outside the window the mousemove event has to be stopped`,i have detected the click outside the window on mouseleave,but how to prevent the default even?in Javascript

```
onTextContainerMouseLeave: function (e) {
 if (this.curDown == true) {
            var value;                
          $(window).on('mouseup', function (e) {
                this.curDown = false;
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });
        }
```

},

Comment: The only reason the `mousemove` event would be triggered while moving the mouse outside of the page would be because the use is click-dragging--clicking down in the page, then moving the mouse outside of it. So if they click outside the page, that means they would have stopped dragging, and the `mousemove` events would stop anyway.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean. What are you doing to trigger these unnecessary `mousemove` events?

Comment: Use unbind function to stop mousemove.

Comment: This should probably have the [tag:jquery] tag, because it is asking about jQuery events. (I *think* they work the same though...)

Comment: @NitinDhomse, i have also performed unbind event but cannot able to prevent the mousemove event

Answer (score 0):

Put a condition inside your on-click that is true if the mouse was inside the control (which you already have according to what is written). If the condition is true then go on with the on-click events. Otherwise nothing happens.

```
$(window).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (yourconditionhere) {
        //Execute your code here --
    }
});
```

Comment: what is condition bro?

Comment: From the main post "i have detected the click outside the window on mouseleave,"  Getting that condition in general is another issue. I can go over it with some details if required.